# Return 'Self' when only have a borrow of self

Tags: rust

In the code below I have a borrow of `self` so how would I return `Self` here? Or would I create a new instance of impl and return that?

```rust
pub fn add_minutes(&self, minutes: i32) -> Self {
  self.minutes += minutes;
  // TODO return Self
}
```

Comment: This is only possible if `Self: Copy`. Or maybe also for `Self: Clone`. More important question: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe to chain methods?: `struct.add_minutes(5).add_seconds(30);`

Comment: Why not make the function `add_minutes(mut self, minutes: i32) -> Self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Clone`, then you can:

```rust
pub fn add_minutes(&self, minutes: i32) -> Self {
  let mut cloned = self.clone();

  clone.minutes += minutes;

  clone
}
```

Though this might be a lot more inefficient than allowing in-place modification:

```rust
pub fn add_minutes(&mut self, minutes: i32) {
  self.minutes += minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create *owned* `Self` from *borrowed* `Self`. You could either `Clone` to have a new copy of an object (and then you can give an ownership of this object to the caller of your function), or you can return a reference to `Self` that would allow you to reborrow it later and chain methods that take `&self`.

Comment: Or you can create a brand new Self from the constituant fields having copied them.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have addressed literally what your question is asking, but I think this may be an xy problem.

It looks like you might just want a way to modify the object that you passed in, in which case you need a mutable borrow of self, and not returning anything:

```rs
pub fn add_minutes(&mut self, minutes: i32) {
  self.minutes += minutes;
}
```